# Format command output in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a output like below from a command

```
IpPrefix
--------
15.181.232.0/21
142.4.160.136/29
3.2.0.0/24
161.188.154.0/23
```

Using above output, need write a command in powershell to get format like :

```
15.181.232.0/21,142.4.160.136/29,3.2.0.0/24,161.188.154.0/23
```

Basically combine multiple lines to one line with comma separated. Please help.

Comment: `(<existing command/pipeline> |ForEach-Object IpPrefix) -join ','`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to PowerShell! The results of commands are objects. This object you have made has at least 1 property called `IpPrefix`. If your object is stored in a variable `$object`, then you can reference the property like this:

```
$object = (some-command -param something)
$object.IpPrefix
```

Once you're got the items in just that one column, without the column header, you now have an array of strings. They're still objects, but they are *string* objects.

The `-join` operator works against arrays.

```
$object = (some-command -param something)
$object.IpPrefix -join ','
```

This will give you what you want in the simplest way possible.

Let's say maybe you don't want to store your data in a variable (aka in Memory). You might have a pipeline or some other situation where storing the data slows you down. You would do that like this:

```
(some-command -param something).IpPrefix -join ','
```

Same idea, different syntax. Hope this helps you understand the shell better!